How to 'polyfill' `interactive-widget=resizes-content` for meta viewport tag on iOS Safari?
Chrome added support for interactive-widget=resizes-content in v108. Firefox also seems to support this as of writing (though it doesn't work correctly in fullscreen).
The resizes-content value makes the browser "push up" the page content when the virtual keyboard is opened, instead of making the keyboard overlay the content.
I've tested up to iOS Safari 17.4 and it doesn't seem to support this.
Is there some way to 'polyfill' this, ideally in versions iOS Safari v15, onwards?
Naively, one might expect something like this to work:
visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.height = window.visualViewport.height+"px";
});

But the problem with this approach is that Safari does some magic to extend the document length when the keyboard comes up for a text input that's near the end of the page - to allow room for the document to extend under the keyboard. This causes (seemingly insurmountable) issues with approaches like the one above.
Related:

Can I test whether the browser supports the viewport meta tag "interactive-widget" property?
navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent - Not supported by Safari, but also not particularly relevant here since this is used for achieving the opposite of resizes-content. Though it could still be used as one component of a polyfill if it were supported.


I don’t know the answer to this either, but I’m likewise very much interested in what you’re asking about here.
